# Webpack Dev Server 4 Proxy problem with multiple routes

Tags: webpack, proxy, webpack-4

I have a [fractal](https://fractal.build/) setup containing a number of pages and components.

When I start the webpack-dev-server (WPDS), it also starts the fractal server. This fractal server runs on port 2222.

When I go to localhost:3333 (WPDS) -> it proxies ***everything*** to localhost:2222 (fractal)

What I am having problems with, is that i need to proxy various ajax requests too. For example `/players/data?etc` would need to proxied to another host, like such: `https://www.external.com/players/data?etc`

I looked into the bypass option, but the `/` rule trumps everything else.
Appreciate suggestions.

*webpack.config.js*

```
const port = process.env.npm_package_config_port_fractal; //2222

const PROXY_TARGET = 'https://www.external.com';

...

proxy: {
  '/': {
    target: `http://localhost:${port}`, // 2222
  },
  // this will be an ajax request
  '/players/**': { . 
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    target: PROXY_TARGET,
  },
  // this will be an ajax request
 '/draw/**': {
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    target: PROXY_TARGET,
  },
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is almost correct.
But the order of rules in proxy configuration is matters.
So with this configuration:

```
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/players': {
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                target: PROXY_TARGET,
            },
            '/draw': {
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                target: PROXY_TARGET,
            },
            '/': {
                target: `http://localhost:${port}`, // 2222
            },
        }
    }
```

and wds reports:
[image]
So it looks like it works.
I didn't see source code of webpack-dev-server, but I think that these rules is just checks for each request.
And checks will look for first matching regexp.

Pseudo examples:

request with url `/draw/2`

/players check failed
/draw check success!

request with url `/images/item.png`

/players check failed
/draw check failed
/ check success!

Comment: this is a good start (I also mistakenly listed `/` first), but how does your answer explain why listing, e.g. `/rest/2.0` first would swallow `/rest/3.0` requests as well? Is it just "regexp" or is it the first matching subpath?